# How can I do shortcut for "overwrite" while uploading via ftp-simple extension on VS Code

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I'm using the ftp-simple extension on VS code. And I'm sick of pressing overwrite button everytime I upload a file to the FTP server.
Can I make a shortcut (like Ctrl+alt+S) to make the extension overwrite without asking when uploading to FTP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see from the extension's [ftp-simple](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humy2833.ftp-simple) documentation there is an option :

> `confirm` - boolean - (option) Only save option. When you save the file,
>   ask if you want to overwrite the file if it already exists.. Default:
>   true

So

```
"confirm" : false,
```

should eliminate the warning/verification you see.